# In HTML using the selenium framework, how can I check if text is present on the page without hitting exception

Tags: python, selenium

I have code, where I find some text:

```
findmenu = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//span[contains(text(),'Localidad')]"))
```

To verify the presence of an element on the page.

In some cases, the search took about 10 seconds and then the program told me the text was not found by throwing an exception.

Comment: Add the html source also

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? What is the issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further on what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **try-except** structure, with the handling of the error you should get if selenium can't find the webElement you are searching for, ie **NoSuchElementException**

You'll get something like this :

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
   findmenu = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//span[contains(text(),'Localidad')]"))
   # stuff you do when your webElement is found
except NoSuchElementException:
   # stuff you do when your webElement is not found
```

On the other hand, if the element you are trying to find takes some time to load, you can use the wait.until method :

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

try:
   WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Localidad')]")))
   # stuff you do when your webElement is found after waiting 'time' second
except TimeoutException:
   # stuff you do when your webElement is not found after waiting 'time' second
```

Comment: Your 2nd answer is the best approach -- in the 1st approach, you may run into the issue of checking for the element before it has loaded onto the page, which may return a false negative. It does depend on the use case -- is the OP searching for the element after initially opening a page, or is this a step later on after a page has been open for some time? A hypothetical question obviously, good answer regardless.